# Why am I seeing this kind of weird emoji-like characters in web page

Tags: browser, website, unicode, special-characters, characters

I'm getting these weird  emoji-like characters when I see the official website of `ballerinalang.com` hosting by `wso2.com`

Can anybody please tell me why am I seeing this kind of stuff? It's really irritating. I can't see a single word but these weird characters.

Here's a Screenshot of the page:

[image]

Comment: I am not sure exactly which page you are having problems with; however, my preliminary guess is that you are missing font(s) -- (even though Google fonts is used...). I would suggest try downloading the `Cairo` font, which seems to dominate the webpage, from Google fonts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have [JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javascript) disabled in your browser or are you using software, such as [NoScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoScript), that may block JavaScript on a website? If you don't know whether JavaScript is being blocked, you can visit [Determine if JavaScript is Enabled](http://support.moonpoint.com/network/web/browser/javascript/javascriptdetect.php) to make that determination.

The site expects to use the Cairo font that a browser will normally automatically download if JavaScript is enabled. I.e., the site has the following JavaScript code on the home page for the site:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   WebFontConfig = {
     google: { families: [ 'Cairo:200,300,400,600,700,900:latin', 'Source+Sans+Pro:400,600,400italic,700italic,700:latin' ] }
   };
   (function() {
     var wf = document.createElement('script');
     wf.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https' : 'http') +
       '://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1.5.18/webfont.js';
     wf.type = 'text/javascript';
     wf.async = 'true';
     var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
     s.parentNode.insertBefore(wf, s);
   })();
</script>
```

[Google makes many fonts available for website developers to use on their websites](http://support.moonpoint.com/fonts/google-fonts.php). Since a visitor to the site may not have that font installed on his system, Google provides JavaScript code that can be included in webpages that will result in the browser automatically fetching the font from a Google font server. You could manually download the [Cairo font](https://fonts.google.com/?query=Cairo) and see if that resolves the problem or enable JavaScript (instructions for [Firefox](http://support.moonpoint.com/blog/blosxom/2014/11/09#enable-javascript)), if you are blocking it in your browser. It is possible that your browser is substituting some [dingbat font](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dingbat), e.g. [wingdings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wingdings), for Cairo that results in the odd display of the page when you view it.